# How to avoid duplicating code with static polymorphism

Tags: c++

I have an interface like this (except much much lengthier than this in the real library code)

```
struct IFoo
{
    virtual void onA(A& a) = 0;
    virtual void onB(A& a) = 0;
    virtual void onC(A& a) = 0;
};
```

and it is common for me to implement different listeners of `IFoo`. Because of this, I designed a helper class like this one:

```
template <class T>
struct IFooHelper {
    virtual void onA(A& a) { static_cast<T*>(this)->onGeneric(a); }
    virtual void onB(B& b) { static_cast<T*>(this)->onGeneric(b); }
    virtual void onC(C& c) { static_cast<T*>(this)->onGeneric(c); }
};
```

so now, when I have a lot of common behavior in a listener, rather than having to provide a virtual override of every single `IFoo` function, I can do something like:

```
struct Fox : public IFooHelper<Fox>
{
    template <class T> void onGeneric(T& t) { //do something general }
    void onD(D& d) { //special behavior only for a type D }
};
```

This has worked fantastically well but now I am implementing a listener for which I want some common behavior, and then update a counter, say, of which type of call it was. In other words, assuming I only have types `A,B,C` as above, my listener would be:

```
struct Ugly : public IFooHelper<Ugly>
{
    void onA(A& a) { //8 lines of common code; //update some counter for type A objs; }
    void onB(B& b) { //8 lines of common code; //update some counter for type B objs; }
    void onC(C& c) { //8 lines of common code; //update some counter for type C objs; }
};
```

In here, the calls have to be very fast (so no lookups) and ideally I would be able to exploit the `IFooHelper` to hoist the common behavior into the template method, and then somehow still be able to distinguish the types. I was thinking something like a template specialized struct with offsets into a static cons char* array..or with values themselves which are char* depending on `T`..is there a better way?

Comment: Hope [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern) helps.

Comment: How about using a separate method for the common code which gets inlined in the other methods?

Comment: @wich, thought about that...at the moment I have it implemented with a macro of template specialized structs with static offsets into the array.

Comment: @PalaceChan In the second block of code, should those functions not have different names?

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas, thanks for pointing that out..yes that was a typo - fixed.

Comment: Why can't A, B and C share a virtual base class?

Comment: @CAFxX, A,B,C are POD structs with members which are accessed directly on the callbacks..not actual classes with any behavior or commonality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if I fully understand what you are looking for, but I'll give it a shot. As a first step, consider this:

```
struct NotSoUgly : public IFooHelper<NotSoUgly>
{
    void updateCounter(A& a) { //update some counter for type A objs; }
    void updateCounter(B& b) { //update some counter for type B objs; }
    void updateCounter(C& c) { //update some counter for type C objs; }

    template <class T> void onGeneric(T& t) {
        //8 lines of common code;
        updateCounter(t);
    }
};
```

Further improvements are possible if you'd show us the content of the `updateCounter()` methods to we could come up with a single generic implementation for that as well, but without seeing the code, it's hard to guess.

Comment: Thanks, This does seem to be the best possible given the current situation. I will make an edit in a couple hours to show what I ended up doing.